# WebView Progress Dialog won't dismiss

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

When a page loads up I show the **Progress Dialog**, and I dismiss it when the page finishes loading. After that if there a picture that loads when I scroll down, the **Progress Dialog** will show up, but doesn't disappears after the picture is loaded. How can I fix this problem?

This is my code, use it and you will know exactly what I mean. I will appreciate it if you can help.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Declaring
    WebView browser;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // Loading
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/cool%20pictures");

        // Progress Dialog
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);

        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                return true;
            }

            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                try {

                    if (pd.isShowing() == false) {
                        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                                "Loading. Please wait...", true);
                    }           

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.dismiss();

                }

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: since I posted this question and I am looking for the solution. Did anyone find anything?

Comment: Thank you. You should post the solution in "edit" as answer and marked it as answer. It worked for me.

Comment: I just did it now, glad you found the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 hours of searching, I figured out the solution. Instead of showing the **ProgressDialog** inside the **onLoadResource** method, I used **onPageStarted** method. So my code would look like this.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;


public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            if (pd.isShowing() == false) {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                        "Loading. Please wait...", true);

            }
        }
```